# Speed up heavy UPDATE..FROM..WHERE PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, bigdata, django-orm

I have 2 big tables

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."linkages" (
        "supplierid" integer NOT NULL,
        "articlenumber" character varying(32) NOT NULL,
        "article_id" integer,
        "vehicle_id" integer
);
CREATE INDEX "__linkages_datasupplierarticlenumber" ON "public"."__linkages" USING btree ("datasupplierarticlenumber");

CREATE INDEX "__linkages_supplierid" ON "public"."__linkages" USING btree ("supplierid");
```

having 215 000 000 records, and

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."article" (
    "id" integer DEFAULT nextval('tecdoc_article_id_seq') NOT NULL,
    "part_number" character varying(32),
    "supplier_id" integer,
    CONSTRAINT "tecdoc_article_part_number_supplier_id" UNIQUE ("part_number", "supplier_id")
) WITH (oids = false);
```

having 5 500 000 records.

I need to update linkages.article_id according article.part_number and article.supplier_id, like this:

```
UPDATE linkages
SET article_id = article.id
FROM
article
WHERE
linkages.supplierid = article.supplier_id AND 
linkages.articlenumber = article.part_number;
```

But it is to heavy. I tried this, but it processed for a day with no result. So I had terminated it.

I need to do this update only once to normalize my datatable structure for using foreign keys in Django ORM. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably exclude updating rows which already have the desire value, `AND article_id IS DISTINCT FROM article.id`

Comment: Please show the EXPLAIN.  (You can't do EXPLAIN ANALYZE, as it never finishes.)

Comment: ANALYXE IS:` Update on __linkages  (cost=327993.85..10869154.78 rows=5044002 width=53)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=327993.85..10869154.78 rows=5044002 width=53)
         Hash Cond: ((__linkages.supplierid = tecdoc_article.supplier_id) AND ((__linkages.datasupplierarticlenumber)::text = (tecdoc_article.part_number)::text))
         ->  Seq Scan on __linkages  (cost=0.00..5989305.24 rows=216530224 width=39)
         ->  Hash  (cost=214837.14..214837.14 rows=5424714 width=23)
               ->  Seq Scan on tecdoc_article  (cost=0.00..214837.14 rows=5424714 width=23)`